# Need to create the Table in Database using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jsp

how can I create the **work_with** class in springBoot. I have tried my approch is that **I have created the manytomany mapping between employee and client class but I was not able to create new colunm which is total_sales within work_with**. Is there any way I can Create the new colunm during mapping and is my approch is right or wrong ? if not what should I do to create the works_with table class/entity and also **want to add ON DELETE CASCADE.**

[image: Table]

I want to create the Entity class just like I have done in below image.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="posts")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class **Post** {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name="post_tittle",length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String tittle;
    
    @Column(name="post_image", nullable = false)
    private String imageName;
    
    private String content;
    
    private Date addedDate;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();
    
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of examples and articles online that explain how ManyToMany mappings work. Just search with your favorite search engine for "JPA ManyToMany" and you will find an article like the following: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany